# Modularizing ui-router state definitions

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to scaffold an angular application by *feature* (module) rather than *type*. I have problems though modularizing state definitions for ui-route.
I divided my app into modules `app.core`, `app.company`, `app.products`.

Now instead of having one big `.config` statement, I imagine my modules should sort of install their own states and routes.

```
// core module (core/module.js)
angular
    .module('app.core', ['ui.router', 'app.company', 'app.products'])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        .state('root', { /* abstract */ })
        .state('home', { /*...*/ })
        .state('404', { /*...*/ })
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');

// company module (company/module.js)
angular
    .module('app.company', ['ui.router'])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        .state('company', { /*...*/ })
        .state('company.aboutus', { /*...*/ })
        .state('company.contactus', { /*...*/ })
    });

// products module (products/module.js)
angular
    .module('app.products', ['ui.router'])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        .state('products', { /*...*/ })
        .state('products.category', { /*...*/ })
        .state('products.detail', { /*...*/ })
    });
```

Angular yells at me it cannot resolve company-related states. And I'm losing confidence whether what I'm after is doable at all...

Comment: Try using a character other than a dot in the state name. I seem to remember running into a similar issue and it had to due with the way nested ui-router states worked.

Comment: @mcgraphix The dot notation is driving me crazy. According to the github manual, the dot and the parent should be automatically resolved, but in fact it is not - I have to provide explicit `parent` property, otherwise the state is not processed.

Answer (score 0):

try removing ui.router from company and products so

```
angular
.module('app.company')
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    .state('company', { /*...*/ })
    .state('company.aboutus', { /*...*/ })
    .state('company.contactus', { /*...*/ })
});

angular
.module('app.products')
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    .state('products', { /*...*/ })
    .state('products.category', { /*...*/ })
    .state('products.detail', { /*...*/ })
});
```

and make sure you have app.core declared before the other modules in your index page.

```
<script src="scripts/app.core.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app.company.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app.products.js"></script>
```